# Is it true that $\log \mathbb E((X Y) /\mathbb E[X]) \ge \mathbb E(X \log(Y)/\mathbb E[X])$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(X, Y)$ be a random vector on $\{1,2,3,\cdots, M\}^2$ with $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]$. I think it might be true that
$$\log \mathbb E(X Y/\mathbb E[X]) \ge \mathbb E(X  \log(Y)/\mathbb E[X]).$$
But I cannot apply Jesen's inequality here, because $x \log(y)$ is not a concave function on $[1,M]^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Jensen's inequality applied to the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, Q)$ where $Q(E)=\int_E \frac X {\mathbb EX} dP$ and the concave function $\log x$.